# Trouble shooting ogr2ogr PostGres conversion to shapefile

Tags: postgresql, convert, ogr

I have a postgres database that I am trying to do a bulk export of to individual shapefiles. The database consists of several hundred tables.

If I run this command:

`ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" dbdata PG:"host=someHostname user=someUser dbname=someDB password=somePassword"`

It exports a small portion of the total table's to a shapefiles with no errors.  When I specifically target one of the tables that failed to convert it results in only the *.dbf file being created.  The `ogrinfo` command returns only the tables that are successfully created.  When I connect ArcMap to the original databse and add the tables that are not being converted to a map they all render, so I know they are "good".

Is there a log or command I can use to output why the tables are failing to be converted?

Version Number: GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25 postgres 9.3

Comment: Adding --debug on should print more information.

Comment: I'll take that as an answer